# Put dropdown values in array in JS Node Selenium Webdriver

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

How can one extract all of the displayed text values in a given `select` (dropdown box) in to an array for later use with Node Selenium Webdriver in JavaScript?

I can't work this out... Maybe I'm just not thinking out of the box enough here.

Here is an example of the box:

```
 <select id="thebox">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Expected Result (an array like this):

```
['Volvo', 'Saab', 'Mercedes', 'Audi']
```

Note that I am looking to place the values in an array for later, not to immediately use them within the `.then()` chain.

Comment: This is not a duplicate. Can you remove the mark? @NarendraR

Comment: I am looking to place the values in an array for later, not to immediately use them within the .then() chain like in the accepted answer on the other question.

Comment: the .then chain in the Dup shows how you can get the optionArray. Modify the code to store whatever you want

Comment: If I knew how to just *modify* code that answers a different question so it worked for this purpose, I wouldn't have to ask how to do that in the first place. It is certainly not as simple as an in-line assignment to the array (that much is clear) and it is also not so immediately obvious that the solution jumps out at me either... So who knows?

Comment: var option_array = await driver.findElements(By.css('#thebox >option'))
 .then(options => {
  return Promise.all(options.map(option => {
   return option.getText();
  }))
 });

Comment: See above comment for the answer to this question which was never a duplicate.